# Working Python Caesar Code - Need Help Understanding First Few Lines of Code

Tags: python, loops, encryption, decode, encode

I have created a Caesar cipher program in python, which encodes, decodes, reads, and writes messages. My solution is fully working, and I am facing no problems. My goal was to complete the task in as little lines of code as possible, and with much research I used some code for inspiration. I tried many different versions but this seems to work the best for me. 
 
All I am asking is that I want to understand how the first 5 essential lines of the code work, the significance of the specific numbers during those couple of lines of code, the loops and functions. I just want a few sentences explaining what process or calculations those 5 lines of code is responsible for and how it executes them. 
 
Any help would be appreciated hugely as I have been researching similar sets of code and have not been able to find any explanation for the code to my writing. Sorry for the lengthy background information. 
 
Below is my whole code:

```
def caesar(s, k, decode = False):
  if decode: k = 26 - k
  return "".join([chr((ord(i) - 65 + k) % 26 + 65)
                for i in s.upper()
                if ord(i) >= 65 and ord(i) <= 90 ])
result = str
decrypt = str
offset = int
exit = False
while(exit == False):
  print " "
  print " " 
  print "Welcome to Caeser's Cipher code, you can encrypt, decrypt, read, and store messages"
  print "DECRYPT - DECRYPT A MESSAGE"
  print "ENCRYPT - ENCRYPT A MESSAGE"
  print "READ - READ AND DECODE A MESSAGE"
  print "EXIT - EXIT THE PROGRAM"

  NoOfLetters = 26
  offset = 0
  option = raw_input("Please Enter your choice: ")

  if(option == "DECODE"):
    decrypt = raw_input("Enter the coded message: ")
    offset = int(raw_input("Enter the  Offset as an integer: "))
    print "Result: "
    print caesar(decrypt, offset, decode = True)
    print

  elif(option == "ENCODE"):
    encrypt = raw_input("Enter the message to code")
    offset = int(raw_input("Enter the Offset as integer: "))d
    print "Result: "
    print caesar(encrypt, offset, decode = False)
    result = caesar(encrypt, offset, decode = False)

    option2 = raw_input("Would you like to store this coded message and offset? (Y/N): ")
    if(option2 == "Y"):
      f = open("code.txt", "w")
      print >> f, result
      print >> f, offset
      f.close()
      print"The message and offset has been stored in a file called 'code.txt'"

  elif(option == "READ"):
    print"The program is reading and decrypting the code stored in 'code.txt'"
    print"The code.txt file is stored in the same location as the application"
    f = open("/Users/Emaad/Desktop/CIPHER CODE/code.txt")
    decrypt = f.readline()
    offset = int(f.readline())
    f.close()
    print "Result:"
    print caesar(decrypt, offset, decode = True)
    print "Offset:"
    print offset


  elif(option == "EXIT"):
    print"Thanks for using..."
    print"exiting the application...."
    exit = True
```

Below are the lines of code which I want to understand:

```
def caesar(s, k, decode = False):
    if decode: k = 26 - k
    return "".join([chr((ord(i) - 65 + k) % 26 + 65)
                for i in s.upper()
                if ord(i) >= 65 and ord(i) <= 90 ])
```

Comment: You claimed to have written this code, yet you don't know how it works? It is more likely that you found this code snippet online somewhere, in which case this is not helping you learn. The reason this is so is your function returns after the second line, making the rest of your code irrelevant.

Comment: I wrote most of this code, as I said the first 5 lines are purely someone else's work but I am unable to find an explanation for how that part works with all the research I have done.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to understand if we split the code into smaller functions:

```
def chr2int(i):
    return ord(i) - 65
```

This is for mapping upper case letters to integers starting from 0. Example:

```
chr2int('A') == ord('A') - 65 == 0
chr2int('B') == ord('B') - 65 == 1
chr2int('Z') == ord('Z') - 65 == 25
```

65 is the decimal code of the uppercase letter 'A'

```
ord('A') == 65
```

rot() adds k to a number n (modulo 26):

```
def rot(n, k):
    return (n + k) % 26
```

26 is the number of all letters from A to Z:

```
ord('Z') - ord('A') + 1 == 26
```

Example:

```
rot(1, 1) == 2
rot(25, 0) == 25
rot(25, 1) == 0
rot(25, 2) == 1
```

int2chr() performs the inverse function of chr2int - converts the integer back to a letter.

```
def int2chr(i):
    return chr(i + 65)
```

Now you can combine the three functions to perform Caeser chiper in one (uppercase) character:

```
def caeser_char(char, key):
    return int2chr(rot(chr2int(char), key))
```

To apply ceaser chiper to a whole word you can use list comprehensions:

```
def ceaser(word, key):
    chars = [caeser_char(i, key)                # perform caeser cipher
             for i in word.upper()              # for each char in word
             if ord(i) >= 65 and ord(i) <= 90]  # only if i is a letter
                                                # (between word('A')==65 and ord('Z')==90)
    return "".join(chars)                       # build a word from a list of chars
```

To decode a word, you only need to find the inverse key which is given by the function:

```
def decode_key(encode_key):
    return 26 - encode_key
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is terrific, it's already helping me loads, I just need a small bit of elaboration on the 'modulo 26' part and what exactly it's needed for.

Comment: 26 is the number of all letters from A to Z. "Modulo" is the operation that "rotates" a number in a range. With "Modulo 12" you can perform arithmetic like an analog clock, 11AM + 2h = 1PM,  (11 + 2) % 12 == 1. Caeser cipher works the same way - you need to add the encryption key to each letter code. Then you do a "modulo 26" operation to rotate around all the possible letters. Ex: 'ZED' + 1(key) = 'AFE', or, (25+1)%26==0, (4+1)%26==5, (5+1)%26==6